# run-time error "undefined" with "import" statement in typescript

Tags: typescript

I have "ErrorMessage.ts" in "com/abc/module/common"

```
module com.abc.module.common {

     export const ErrorMessages = {

      ITEM_ALREADY_EXISTS:  "item already exists",

      ITEM_NOT_FOUND: "not found"

 };

}
```

in itemMaint.ts in "com/abc/module/item", I have

```
module com.abc.module.item {

       import ErrorMessages = com.abc.module.common.ErrorMessages;

console.log(ErrorMessages.ITEM_NOT_FOUND);

}
```

At run-time, I got error: ITEM_NOT_FOUND of undefined.

After I added `///<reference path="../common/ErrorMessages.ts" />` to the top of "itemMaint.ts", the error is gone. Can you please tell me why I have to add it?

Thanks,

Bob

Answer (score 0):

I think that the right way to `import` is this :

`import { module } from "modulePath";`

You can read more here https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing concepts between modules and namespaces, terminology is also confusing (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html)

What you are actually building, i think is called a namespace, which at the end is a variable containing all your exported methods and variables, check the transpilled files, to see it.

So to "import" on the nested file you only need to include/execute "ErrorMessage.ts" before "itemMaint.ts" withoout using "import" because it's already there because the variable has already been created.

This is old style, and should not be used, there are better ways to declare modules using ES6 syntax and a module loader.